# Why do I get two different outputs here?

Tags: c++, boost, floating-point

The following two pieces of code produce two different outputs.

```
//this one gives incorrect output
cpp_dec_float_50 x=log(2)
std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<cpp_dec_float_50>::digits)<< x << std::endl;
```

The output it gives is

> 0.69314718055994528622676398299518041312694549560547

which is only correct upto the 15th decimal place. Had x been double, even then we'd have got first 15 digits correct. It seems that the result is overflowing. I don't see though why it should. cpp_dec_float_50 is supposed to have 50 digits precision.

```
//this one gives correct output
cpp_dec_float_50 x=2
std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<cpp_dec_float_50>::digits)<< log(x) << std::endl;
```

The output it gives is

> 0.69314718055994530941723212145817656807550013436026

which is correct according to wolframaplha .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really just a complex version of:

```
float a = 1 / 2;
```

Here, `1 / 2` is integer division because the parameters are integers. It's only converted to a `float` to be stored in `a` *after* the result is computed.

C++ rules for how to compute a result do not depend on what you do with that result. So the actual calculation of `log(2)` is the same whether you store it in an `int`, a `float`, or a `cpp_dec_float_50`.

Your second bit of code is the equivalent of:

```
float b = 1;
float c = 2;
float a = b / c;
```

Now, you're calling `/` on a `float`, so you get floating point division. C++'s rules *do* take into account the types of arguments and paramaters. That's complex enough, and trying to also take into account what you do with the result would make C++'s already overly-complex rules incomprehensible to mere mortals.

Comment: 1/2? 0? What does it have to do with the question?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: It's precisely the same issue. The OP is expecting what he does with a result to affect how it is calculated. It does not, only how it is converted *after* it's calculated.

Comment: Then you should perhaps also mention that `double` (which is what `log(2)` returns) has many fewer significant digits than `cpp_dec_float_50` (which is, I assume, what `log(x)` returns).

Comment: The OP mentions that, but he thinks the issue is overflowing. It's not. The issue is that he's calling `log` on something that's not a `cpp_dec_float_50` and expecting what he does with it to change how it was computed in the first place.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It would explain why the first code gives the incorrect output. Had I typed cpp_dec_float_50 x=log(cpp_dec_float_50(2)), it gives correct output. What this doesn't explain however is why 2nd code gives correct output.

Comment: @NikharAgrawal: The second code calls `log` on a `cpp_dec_float_50`. The first stores the result of a log operation in a `cpp_dec_float_50`. It's precisely analogous to the division example I give.

Comment: @NikharAgrawal In the second case you're using not C++'s `log()`, but Boost's.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Oh, I'm sorry I was confused. I incorrectly remembered that I called log(2) instead of log(x) in the second code and the result was correct. I remembered wrongly. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: Ok..now that has me a little confused. I'm not very strong on namespaces so pardon me if its a stupid question. When I call C++'s log(), this is in global namespace as well as std namespace. Is the boost log (overloaded for cpp_float_dec_50) also in global namespace?

Comment: @NikharAgrawal In C++ you can have multiple functions with the same name but different parameters, right?

Comment: @NikharAgrawal: It doesn't have to be, thanks to [Koenig lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup). Otherwise `std::cout << 2;` wouldn't work since `std::string::operator<<(int)` isn't in the global namespace.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Yes I get that. Maybe I phrased my question incorrectly. Is boost's log() also in global namespace? And not in some special namespace, so that we'd have to call it like this (for example)->boost::log()

Comment: This is an overly wordy answer which never gets around to explicitly stating that `log(2)` calls the standard `log(double)` function whereas the asker wants `log(cpp_dec_float_50)` or that the latter is achieved by calling `log` with a `cpp_dec_float_50` argument.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: It's the whole teach a man to fish versus give a man a fish thing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It **omits the actual answer**. Analogies may help people learn, if they understand the prerequisite idea or it is clearly explained, and the analogy from that first idea to the second is explained. This answer does not explain well and does not actually complete the analogy or explain the cause of the problem.

Comment: Here are two critical statements that are missing from this answer: `log(2)` is evaluated with `double`, because the best match for this by C++ rules is the standard `log(double)` function. To get the `log` for the `cpp_dec_float_50` type, you can use `cpp_dec_float_50 x = 2; log(x);`.

Answer (score 5):

When you do `log(2)`, you're using the implementation of `log` in the standard library, which takes a double and returns a double, so the computation is carried out to double precision.

Only after that's computed (to, as you noted, a mere 15 digits of precision) is the result converted to your 50-digit extended precision number.

When you do:

```
cpp_dec_float_50 x=2;
/* ... */ log(x);
```

You're passing an extended precision number to start with, so (apparently) an extended precision overload of `log` is being selected, so it computes the result to the 50 digit precision you (apparently) want.